# Guaranteed scheduling vs Fair-Share Scheduling

Tags: operating-system, scheduling

I am studying for my Operating Systems course then I came across the scheduling topic.

Can anybody compare guaranteed scheduling and fair-shared scheduling for me?
Internet sources are not comparing them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The guaranteed scheduling can be considered whether the progress is guaranteed or not. where as fair share scheduling can be consider under bounded waiting time.

Progress is guaranteed when a process outside the critical section should not stop the other process to enter the critical section.

Bounded waiting time is similar like fair scheduling in which within certain bounded time the process should get the chance to enter critical section.

Answer (score 0):

They would appear to be basically the same thing: an attempt to evenly divide CPU time between users (or groups of users), or in other words, guarantee each gets a fair share :).

Comment: Are there any significant advantages or disadvanteges of any of them? Which one is choosen under which circumstances? Thanks by the way :)